# $R[x]$-algebra structure that on $R[y]$ seen as quotient of $R[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, affine-schemes, algebras

In a broader exercise about the fibered product of schemes, I'm given a ring (commutative and unitary) $R$ and the following ring homomorphism:

$\begin{align*}
R[x]&\to R[y]\\
x&\mapsto y^2\\
\end{align*}$

which gives $R[y]$ an $R[x]$-algebra structure. My hope is to prove that, as an $R[x]$-algebra, $R[y]$ is isomorphic to $\frac{R[x][y]}{(x-y^2)}$. Is this true? How can I prove this? It appears obvious to me, but maybe I'm missing something.

**Edit:** as suggested in the comments, the explicit isomorphism by the two should be as follows:

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{R[x,u]}{(x-u^2)} &\rightarrow R[y]\\
x&\mapsto y^2 \\
u&\mapsto y
\end{align*}
$

this is an $R[x]$-algebra homomorphism (with the obvious $R[x]$-algebra structure on the first ring) and has the following inverse:

$
\begin{align*}
R[y] &\rightarrow \frac{R[x,u]}{(x-u^2)}\\
y&\mapsto u
\end{align*}
$

(I checked that both are $R[x]$-algebra homomorphisms and are in fact one the inverse of the other)

Correct me if I'm wrong or if there was a non-explicit way!

Comment: You could try showing that there is an isomorphism $R[x,u]/(x-u^2) \rightarrow R[y]$ explicitly. The left-hand side has a natural $R[x]$-structure and you have imposed one on the right-hand side. (I used the variable $u$ so that you find it easier to distinguish the universes in which everything lives.)

Comment: @tkr I kinda wanted to avoid the explicit way, but if there is no other method I'll just do that (I guess it shouldn't be too hard).

Comment: @Avenaldo I appreciate that. The questions is explicit in my eyes, though. Perhaps you can edit your question with an example of a similar result you know how to prove in an "inexplicit" way, as motivation for an answerer.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the kernel of the surjective homomorphism $R[x,u]\to R[y], x\mapsto y^2, u\mapsto y$ is $(x-u^2)$ so that it induces the desired isomorphism.

By thinking of $R[x,u]$ as $R[x][u]$, $u^2-x$ is a monic polynomial and any element of it has a representation $(u^2-x)P(u)+au+b, a,b\in R[x]$. If its image in $R[y]$ is zero, we must have $a=b=0$.